# How to use the Lambert W function in an equation like this?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, lambert-w

I was thinking of $\frac{4}{3}$ and found that $(\frac{4}{3})^4$ roughly equals $3$ (*very* roughly), and I though I would try to find the pairs of numbers where the equality suffices. So given the equation

$(\frac{a}{b})^a = b$,

how does one rearranges the sides so that the Lambert $W$ function becomes somehow applyable? Or am I getting it completely wrong and it's not the $W$ function but something completely different that is needed in cases like this?

Comment: One equation for two unknowns looks like the system is underdetermined. Or are you searching for integer $a,b$. (then indeed Lambert-W function is completely misleading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=be^x$

$b=(\frac{a}{b})^a$

$\ln(b)=a\ln(\frac{a}{b})=a\ln(e^x)=ax=be^xx$

$xe^x=\frac{\ln(b)}{b}$

$x=W(\frac{\ln(b)}{b})$

$a=be^{W(\frac{\ln(b)}{b})}$

Comment: I see what you're doing there, expressing $\frac{a}{b}$ as $e^x$, genius.

Comment: In case $b=3$, $a=3e^{W(\frac{\ln(3)}{3})}$, approximately = 3.9593664536344768966766791807208880469899151254601756 from WolframAlpha.

Comment: Where can you calculate with values inside WA?

Comment: See the example here :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3exp%28LambertW%28ln%283%29%2F3%29%29&lk=4&num=4